Feynman rules in position and momentum space
I want to understand and learn how can I draw the rules for different spaces, when I am considering an $S$-matrix element.
Let's consider a $2\rightarrow2$ process and the interaction is of the form $\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \phi)(\partial^\mu \phi) -\frac{m^2}{2}\phi^2 -\frac{\lambda}{4!}$.
The initial state can be i.e. $|i\rangle=|\vec p_1,\vec p_2\rangle=a^\dagger(\vec p_1)a^\dagger(\vec p_2)|0\rangle$
The final state:
$|f\rangle=|\vec p_3,\vec p_4\rangle=a^\dagger(\vec p_3)a^\dagger(\vec p_4)|0\rangle$
If we consider $\langle f|s|i\rangle$ and we know that $s=Texp[i\int \mathcal{L}_wd^4x]$, $$ then in first order perturbation theory, we will get no propagator, that is why I considered 2nd order where I get to deal with propagators, since I need to write feynmann rules in position and momentum space, and a rule for the propagator needs to be given.
In 2nd order:
$$\langle 0|a_3a_4\int T[\phi(x)\phi(x)\phi(x)\phi(x)\phi(y)\phi(y)\phi(y)\phi(y)]d^4xd^4y a^\dagger_1a^\dagger_2|0\rangle.$$
I found out that out of many contractions those who work (and their different permutations which represent physically the same feynmann diagram) are 3, and correspond to the s-channel, t-channel and u-channel. I will just consider the s-channel. One has:
$$\frac{i^2(-\lambda)^2}{2(4!)^2}\langle 0|\int e^{ip_3x}e^{ip_4x}D_F(x-y)D_F(x-y)e^{-ip_1y}e^{-ip_2y}d^4xd^4y$$
This term I got by, starting from the left, contracting first field operator from the left with either $a_3$ or $a_4$, then the 2nd one in line is contracted with the other annihilation operator, the 4 field operators that follow are contracted between themselves, with the condition that two contracted field operators must have different arguments, i.e. $x^\mu$ and $y^\mu$, and the last 2 field operators are contracted with the creation operators to the right.
The point of this thread is to understand how can i deduce or produce the feynmann rules in both spaces (position and momentum).
What I wrote above is the integration in positions space, so I believe I can draw conclusions for position. And If I would want to find the rules in momentum space, then I would need to integrate over space, meaning over $d^4xd^y$ and find the rules in momentum space.
But a main question is, what does constitute a rule. For example in position space, for which I have written the integral, what constitutes a rule?
My suspicion is that in positon space i.e :
a vertex is: $-i\lambda$
a propagator is: $D_F(x-y)$
An external line would be: $e^{-ipx}$ or $e^{ipx}$.
But I don't know whether there are more and I don't know whether my reasoning for how to get these rules in momentum space is correct. And I want to have good understanding of this distinction made (rules in position and momentum space), because it has been an issue for me, for a while now.

Linked.

The terms of a lagrangian have fields in them so you should indicate what those are. How do we know if it's $\phi^2$ vs $\phi^4$? That way we could know what you model you've chosen (seems to be some scalar $\phi$ theory).

@Triatticus I don't understand. What do you mean?

You give your interaction....only with the coupling constant, that's not what an interaction term looks like, it should look like some coupling constant multiplied by fields which show what fields are interacting at this point. Like how $\phi^4$ theory would have $-\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^4$. You basically leave us to guess what your model and fields are.

@Triatticus I see. I edited the post and I wrote the full lagrangian density

Have you tried writing the states $|k_1k_2\rangle$ in terms of fields using the LSZ theorem? Maybe this will clarify things, especially with regard to the external legs, since then you're dealing with field operators only. The Feynman rules come from writing out the series expansion and then inventing graphical rules for it, so in this sense your reasoning is correct, but I'm having a little difficulty understanding what exactly you're asking, since the rules themselves are found in any standard textbook.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/810785
